# Angular 2 animationDone()

Tags: angular

I've been playing with Angular 2 animations and used the `animationDone($event)` method to change variable value and run another animation. This is what I did:

HTML:

```ts
<div class="jumbotron text-center" (click)="nice=!nice">
<h1 (@flyInOut.start)="animationStarted($event)"
        (@flyInOut.done)="animationDone($event)"
        [@flyInOut]="'in'"
        >Welcome to the new world</h1>
        {{go}}
</div>
```

My TS:

```ts
  animations: [
  trigger('flyInOut', [
    state('in', style({transform: 'translateX(0)'})),
    transition('void => *', [
      animate(1500, keyframes([
        style({opacity: 0, transform: 'translateX(-100%)',     offset: 0}),
        style({opacity: 0, transform: 'translateX(-30px)', offset: 0.3}),
        style({opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(0)',  offset: 1.0})
      ]))
    ]),
    transition('* => void', [
      animate(300, keyframes([
        style({opacity: 0, transform: 'translateX(100%)',     offset: 0}),
        style({opacity: 0, transform: 'translateX(-15px)', offset: 0.3}),
        style({opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(0)',  offset: 1.0})
      ]))
    ])
  ])
]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';

  private go = false;

  animationStarted($event)
  {

  }
  animationDone($event) {
      this.go = true;
      console.log("Executed GO");
  }
}
```

The `go` variable is changing from `false` to `true` when the animation complete, Although my template `{{go}}` shows **false** output.

Is it error with Angular or with something I tried to do?

Comment: Can you please try to add `constructor(this.cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef){}` and then call `this.cdRef.detectChanges()` after `this.go = true;`?

Comment: Worked like a magic. Seem like the `detectChanges()` are not applied after the `animationDone($event) ` method.

Comment: Glad to hear this worked. I don't know if this is a bug or by design but I guess it is one. It seems the animation somehow runs outside Angulars zone. When the event handler does more work than just changing local properties, it might be better to use `zone.run(() => {...})` instead of `detectChanges()`

Comment: seems like a bug to me...

Comment: This is due a bug where animation callbacks run outside angular's zone, already reported over here https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11881